# Related entities not loading when using Include with Linq to Entities

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

In my schema, I have the following relevant entities:

[Basic schema for Element/Folder/User/Role](http://s27.postimg.org/uhlju8m8z/Folder_Access.png)

I'm trying to load a list of the Folders that each User has access to - either directly or by virtue of the User having a Role that has access to the Folder. I've split the requirement into two pieces (direct and indirect) and used a Union to pull the records back in a single collection, with only one call to the database.

I've got the L2E statement below running - as long as a User has a (direct or indirect) record in Access, the Folder entity will be returned in the list (Note: sUserElmKey is the key of the current User).

```
Dim fldList = (From fld As Folder In ctxClient.Elements.OfType(Of Folder)() _
               Join acs As Access In ctxClient.Accesses
               On acs.ElementKey Equals fld.ElementKey
               Where acs.UserRoleElementKey = sUserElmKey _
               Select fld
              ).Union _
              (From fld As Folder In ctxClient.Elements.OfType(Of Folder)() _
               Join acs As Access In ctxClient.Accesses
               On acs.ElementKey Equals fld.ElementKey
               Join rol As Role In ctxClient.Elements.OfType(Of Role)()
               On rol.ElementKey Equals acs.UserRoleElementKey
               Where (From usr As User In rol.Users
                      Where usr.ElementKey = sUserElmKey).Any _
               Select fld
              )
```

This worked fine when I just needed to know if *any* access to each Folder was available to the User. Now I need to define other logic based on which AccessTypeCode the User has for each Folder.

Given that I need to iterate over the resulting entities in the collection in order to load a different collection of objects that represents nodes in the tree UI, I figured I'd just add an Include("Accesses") to each sub-statement above. As I iterated through the resulting collection, I could write the logic to set the needed flags for each of the new node objects (e.g. if the User has AccessTypeCode "VIEW", then they have read-only access; "OWN" or "NEW" and they have read/write access).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find where to add the Include to do this properly - I've put it after the "ctxClient.Elements" as well as after the ".OfType(Of Folder()", but while the code compiles and runs, the debugger shows 0 records for the Accesses collection under each Folder when I'm iterating.

Rewriting this as a lambda expression is an option, but I think I might just find myself in the same place.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Is `Accesses` a navigation property of `Folder`?

Comment: `Accesses` is a navigation property of `Element`, which is the super-class of `Folder`.

Comment: Uploaded pic of schema

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you schema I think you can rewrite the query as follows:

```
(From fld In ctxClient.Elements.OfType(Of Folder)()
 Where fld.Accesses.Any(Function(acs) acs.UserRoleElementKey = sUserElmKey)
 Select fld)
.Union
(From fld In ctxClient.Elements.OfType(Of Folder)()
 Where fld.Accesses.Any(Function(acs) acs.UserRoleElement.Users
                       .Any(Function(usr) usr.ElementKey = sUserElmKey))
Select fld)
```

This checks whether there is *any* access, directly or through roles, without having to `Include` accesses.

Comment: This is cleaner than mine, however I see a couple of issues: 1) Access.UserRoleElement navigates to Element, not directly to Role, so don't I need some way to indicate that .Users is from Role, not Element? 2) I'm looking for a way to be able to Include all records in Access for this User (I need to have this data at that granular level).

Comment: This is really hard to figure out without the code base. You could include a test whether `UserRoleElement` is a `Role`. It looks like you should be able to add `Include("Accesses")` right after `ctxClient.Elements`, but apparently it doesn't load the accesses. I can't figure out why not.